# Laravel Eloquent counts with multiple ranges of data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to create Laravel query that will produce me with the following mysql query.

```
select
 count(CASE WHEN points BETWEEN 0 AND 1.99 THEN 1 END) as count0_199,
 count(CASE WHEN points BETWEEN 2 AND 3.99 THEN 1 END) as count2_399,
 count(CASE WHEN points BETWEEN 4 AND 5.99 THEN 1 END) as count4_599
from
 stats
```

Is it possible to make it in Eloquent? Haven't seen it in the documentation.
Thanks

Comment: Did you hope to achieve this in one eloquent query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my knowledge using eloquent to perform this will involve some formatting of returned data:

```
$results = [];

$stats = Stat::where('points', '>=', '0')
    ->where('points', '<=', 5.99)
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($stat, $key) use (&$results) {
        if ($stat->points >= 0 && $stat->points <= 1.99) {
            $results['count0_199'][] = $stat;
        }

        if ($stat->points >= 2 && $stat->points <= 3.99) {
            $results['count2_399'][] = $stat;
        }

        if ($stat->points >= 4 && $stat->points <= 5.99) {
            $results['count4_599'][] = $stat;
        }
    });

return $results;
```

In the code above, all stats where points are between `0` and `5.99` are returned (as they will be returned anyway). The returned collection is then looped through to populate a `$results` array which will group the returned data.

There is also the [`DB` Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database):

```
$query = [
    'count(CASE WHEN points BETWEEN 0 AND 1.99 THEN 1 END) as count0_199',
    'count(CASE WHEN points BETWEEN 2 AND 3.99 THEN 1 END) as count2_399',
    'count(CASE WHEN points BETWEEN 4 AND 5.99 THEN 1 END) as count4_599'
];

$results = DB::select(implode(',', $query) . ' from stats');
```